# Issue while executing touch command in Docker

Tags: docker

I have an issue while executing touch command in **Docker**.

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: Can you describe exactly the steps you are performing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to touch a file inside container, the container should be running. You can touch a file by running

```
docker run <image_name> bash -c "touch /path/to/file/<filename>"
```

If you are trying this inside dockerfile, then you should use `RUN touch /path/to/file/<filename>`